# Custom Script for Linux - how to execute bash script from particular folder

Tags: linux, bash, azure, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure.

We have created one small website just as a POC in which I need to select the VM name and Resource group name in which that VM is present. And then I need to mention the command which I need to execute and then click on execute button which will execute the command.

Now what I did, I created one bash script file named as trial.sh in user home directory in Linux. Now I am trying to execute it by giving

> ./trial.sh

Something like this -

[image]

But when I am checking under Azure portal VM extension it is giving me an error as -

```
Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=127 [stdout] [stderr] /bin/sh: ./trial.sh: No such file or directory
```

So by seeing the error that I guessing that I am creating bash file in wrong location. So just want to know that where should I keep the file under Linux VM so that it will not give me this error and will run successfully.

Note: In pic the in "Command file path" option I need to mention blob storage path where my script is present. But my requirement is that the script should be present in Linux VM itself.

I have also gone through this link but no luck - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

Can someone please help me with this requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you put the executable script in one of the directories shown from the PATH environmental variable, you can then execute it without the ./ and with just trail.sh. Somewhere like /usr/local/bin should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute path like

```
/user_home_directory/trial.sh
```

Note: dot charater in `./` mean your current directory

Comment: You don't need "." at the start when executing using the full path

Comment: Thank you for your time an response . I ran "/home/saurabh/trial.sh" command and status is showing successfully ran. But in trial.sh I have given content as "touch a.txt" under trial.sh, but I am not able to see any a.txt file in that path. Can you please help me with this?!

Comment: because you're trying to create file a.txt in where you run the script. Two solution, you should `touch /fullpath/a.txt` or you should `cd` to directory where you want to create file then `touch` the file

Comment: Thank you @LuanPhan for your response. I have given as touch /home/saurabh/a.txt as well as tried with cd solution also but still not working .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing working dir in a subshell, and execute the command.
This is the bash syntax

```
(cd SOME_PATH && exec_some_command)
```